# How to keep my music and alarm files separate

Tags: applications, music, music-player, alarm, mp3

I have two folders of mp3 files, one for music and one for my alarm clock. I have them both on my sd card.

Right now I'm trying to use (or find) 3rd party apps that will do what i want.

Even outside the default music folder,  the music player and the alarm app both seem to pick up both folders.

I'd like to find a way to ignore the folders in each app. I tried adding a .nomedia folder but that hides it from both apps.

If there's a specific app that can ignore .nomedia files or only look at specified folders, that would probably work.

Seems most alarm apps name you select each song (let me know of any that can just watch folders), but it's still annoying sorting through picking out which is alarm and which isn't.

Comment: Please note that recommendations like *Is there an app for X* are off-topic here (see [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic) for details). For where your question might fit better, you might want to look into [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](//android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575) and [Where to ask for app recommendations?](//android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2060/16575).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Folder player does that for you.
I use the pro version for years now. (I'm a fan).
But the free version works just fine for this purpose.
Just select a home folder in the settings. 
I always select the directory above the Music folder, so I'm able to shuffle trough al the mp3's.

Hope this works out for you.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.folderplayer