# Mysterious and whimsical selection of ringtones recognized by clock as alarms

Tags: samsung, alarm, ringtone, custom-sounds, samsung-galaxy-tab-a

I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab A with S pen. I am trying to add additional alarm sounds to the list used by the native alarm clock app provided by Samsung, as these lack personality and often fail to wake me. I copied all the ringtones from my phone to Dropbox, and then exported them to the Ringtones folder with the Dropbox export feature.

Of the sixty-odd ringtones so exported, exactly four appeared in the alarm clock list of available sounds. I can discern no pattern in the ringtones so appearing. All 60 are all of the same file type, .mp3s. They are not especially long or short, nor large or small. They are neither clustered together under any file sort view nor evenly spaced. I have played all the files with six different player apps, all such apps that I have installed. With one exception, every app played all the files without difficulty.

The exception is the Sound Picker, invoked via the plus sign at the top of the clock's list of alarm sounds. The Sound Picker shows the four ringtones the clock sees, and four more, again with no obvious pattern; also a bunch of short snippets of some lecture that I do not recognize. The sound picker allows me to add exactly one of these new sounds to the clock's list. Adding another removes the one previously added.

I am completely befuddled by this and have no idea how to proceed further. Any insight or diagnostic suggestions welcome.

Comment: IDK what causes this but solution [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/226595) may help

Comment: Thanks @beeshyams! I have used ringtone maker apps in the past, but this one is much easier to use.  I found, through no insight of my own, a mysterious solution to my mysterious problem. My ringtones appeared in the new location at a rate of one per several hours. Three days later they were all there. Why so slow? No idea. No visable reformatting of the files.

Answer (score 0):

I found, through no insight of my own, a mysterious solution to my mysterious problem. My ringtones appeared in the new location at a rate of one per several hours. Three days later they were all there. Why so slow? No idea. There was no visable reformatting of the files.